# Not understanding a question for a mathematical model using functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You work forty hours a week at a furniture store. You receive $\$220$ as a weekly salary, plus a $3\%$ commission on sales over $5000$ dollars. Create a function to calculate the total amount you would get paid.

So the first part seems fairly simple and I think I got it down. This is the function I created:

let $P=$ pay let $s=$ sales
$$ P(s)=\left\lbrace  \begin{array}{ll} 220+0.03s\quad & \text{if}\quad s>5000 \\ 220\quad & \text{if}\quad s\le 5000 \end{array} \right.$$

Now the next part is: 
Create a function to determine the amount of sales you'll have over $5000$.

I have no idea how I would go about doing this. I feel like this question is either poorly worded or I am just not getting it.

Could somebody give me their insight on this?

Comment: My interpretation of the deal is that if $s\gt 5000$ you get $220+(0.03)(s-5000)$.

Comment: I thought the commission was on sales over 5000 dollars.  If it were to be the case then $P = 220+0.03\times(Max(S-5000,0))$.  Thus if s is greater than 5000, you will get the commission, else you just get the weekly salary.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, bingo, same interpretation here but with one function

Comment: Your version is definitely more compact. I tend to like piecewise defined functions. Takes more space, but pixels are cheap.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Yes, Chief Agreed

Comment: @AndréNicolas so what are you trying to say? That my first function is wrong?

Comment: I would not call it exactly wrong, it is one interpretation of the contract. But I think the more natural interpretation of the words is the one that I and satish ramanathan took, that you get extra bucks only for the amount *over* $5000$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What do you think of the second part to this model?
"Create a function to determine the amount of sales you'll have over 5000"

Comment: It is not clear what they intend. To put it brutally, this is educationese, no mathematician would write like this. Maybe they mean $0$ if $s\le 5000$, $s-5000$ otherwise. Or maybe they want this as a function of your income.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I feel like the second part is asking how many sales they made that were each worth over $5000. Which would be impossible to determine because each sale can be of a different value.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, If the total income is given, assuming it is the pay, then the funcion for sales over 5000 would be $S-5000 = S_{>5000} = \frac{(P-220)}{.03}$.  That will be the sales you will have more than 5000, provided P is greater than 220, in other words, you had income due to sales being more than 5000.

Comment: I interpret it as *total* sales over $5000$. That does not mean I am right, it is just a very poorly worded question.

Comment: So you mean as the total amount of sales that were made that were over $5000$?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, That will be the closest interpretation with the information given.